# How to easily make a mesh of (sphere) 3d points over a vector?

Tags: java, math, 3d, processing

Recently i've been trying to equally distribute points over a 3d sphere surface, after some research this is my code in processing (java) :

```
import peasy.*;
PVector[] points_;

PVector[] generatePoints(int numberOfPoints){
    PVector[] points = new PVector[numberOfPoints];
    float gr = (float) (3-Math.sqrt(5));
    float lambda = PI * gr;
    
    for(int i=0; i<numberOfPoints; i++){
      float t = (float)i/numberOfPoints;
      float a1 = acos(1-2*t);
      float a2 = lambda * i;
      float x = sin(a1) * cos(a2);
      float y = sin(a1) * sin(a2);
      float z = cos(a1);
      PVector p = new PVector(x,y,z).mult(30);
      points[i] = p;
               
    }
    return points;
}


void setup(){
    
   size(600,600,P3D);
   PeasyCam cam = new PeasyCam(this,100);
   cam.setMinimumDistance(50);
   cam.setMaximumDistance(500);
   points_ = generatePoints(1000);
}
void draw(){

  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(2);
  for(int i=0; i<points_.length; i++){
 
  point(points_[i].x,
        points_[i].y,
        points_[i].z);
  }
  
}
```

The thing is that the points are generated following a similar algorithm to the golden spiral one, so i can not do something like draw triangles based on the actual point, the next one and the one below...
any ideas?

This is what I have.

[image: this is what i have]

This is what I want.

[image: this is what i want]

Comment: Congratulations on successfully distributing points uniformly on a sphere! A surprisingly high number of people fail at that task and then don't even realize they failed. I do not understand your sentence "i can not do something like draw triangles based on the actual point, the next one and the one below". Why can't you draw triangles?

Comment: I could be misunderstanding what you want but can't you simply use [beginShape()](https://processing.org/reference/beginShape_.html) use your list of points to create the vertexes and let processing do the job of creating the triangles?

Comment: @Stef Hi! thanks for your comment, the problem is that the way the points are being generated in such a way that i can not join them easily, in other projects i did the points were stored in a 2d matrix in such a way that for the position m[i][j] i was able to join that point to the points m[i+1] and m[i][j+1] to form a triangle, like this "terrain simulation" i did time ago https://editor.p5js.org/LiaIndex/present/p9gP9cYS6 i was thinking in somehow for each point find the nearest points to it and join them.

Comment: @statox Hi!, unfortunately for the way the points are generated processing don't know how to join them correctly.

Comment: Quick update, the method i posted above doesn't work for a number of points greater than 18K sorry.

Answer (score 0):

seems like the term you're looking for is triangulation. In 2D you would mostly use Delaunay-Triangulation, as it yields very pretty triangles. I have never seen it used in 3D, but according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) there seems to exist a version of it for more than two dimensions (also MATLAB offers a toolbox with 3D Delaunay).